# Intermediate rounding

Tags: c, c99

If I have a condition like;

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;

if ((a/b) > 0) ...
```

Is the intermediate result (a/b) threated like a float (0.33) or as an int (0 because of rounding)? I'm coming from the VB6 world, and there this condition would evaluate to false, because when dividing two integers the intermediate result will also be an integer (and 0 > 0 = false).

Comment: It's all integers here...

Answer (score 8):

Dividing two integers results in integer division, i. e. the result is truncated. In this case, it would always evaluate to 0. If you want the result to be a floating-point value, you can simply divide an int by a float, a float by an int or two floats. (Similar behavior can be achieved by casting at least one of the operands to a floating-point type.)

Comment: Would writing ((float)(a/b) > 0) fix it? Or how is that normally done?

Comment: @Joshua No, `(float)(a / b)` casts the result only. You need to cast at least one of the **operands,** like `((float)a / b)`.